# Setting Up Environments/Accounts in SuiteCloud IDE

Tags: ide, netsuite, suitecloud

I've had my SuiteCloud IDE set up with access to the Production and Sandbox environments for years now with no issue. I recently refreshed my sandbox, and with it got the new Sandbox architecture (i.e. no more sandbox domain, it's just a role in the production account). It seems that the IDE and all SuiteAnswers documentation have not caught up with this change. I can't get my IDE connected to my sandbox. I've had a ticket open for a week with NS Support and they can't seem to figure it out either. They keep linking me to articles that haven't been updated to reflect the new architecture.

While testing and re-configuring, I ended up wiping out my accounts and environments to create them anew, thinking maybe this was a good idea. Now I can't even connect to the Production environment. I've tried "system.netsuite.com" as well as the new account-specific domains (i.e. 123456.shop.netsuite.com, or 123456.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com, etc). All of those fail with a message that my info is either invalid or it can't access the URL.

Furthermore, we use Celigo for syncing orders from Amazon, eBay, and our Magento website into Netsuite. They also have a sandbox connection, and they too are struggling to get their sandbox connector linked to the Sandbox account. They're a RECOMMENDED PARTNER and yet somehow don't have any clue how to use this new architecture.

I'm baffled that this hasn't been addressed in their documentation and no one seems to know what to do. So that's why I'm reaching out the community. Has anyone set up the IDE in the newest NetSuite architecture? If so, can you please help me get this working?

Thanks!

P.S. I haven't gotten into the SDF yet, but I'm wondering if that's necessary in order for this to work. Again, NS support didn't say, but is that the new way of doing things or can I still use the same old IDE like I always have been?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured this out and thought I'd share my results.  I knew that the SB account IDs had changed, but I didn't put 2 and 2 together that it would affect the IDE. Evidently, neither did anyone else. If you had your IDE configured already prior to the change, you likely only had a single account configured in the IDE. The Environments contained the credentials and the account was the same for both Production and Sandbox. After you refresh your sandbox the Sandbox environment no longer works because it's trying to use the wrong account. It's made even more complicated by the fact that, if your IDE is already configured, you can't re-run the setup wizard, it's greyed out. Even if you uninstall the IDE out of Eclipse and re-install it saves your configuration and you STILL can't run the wizard. However, I found a helpful menu item under **NetSuite -> Troubleshoot -> Reset Master Password and Account Info**. This removes everything and re-runs the wizard. When you run the wizard it asks for your credentials and automatically finds the accounts, this time both of them, and adds them to the IDE. From that point on, targeting one or the other is very much the same as it was before, except you pick a new account AND a new environment from the project settings instead of just a new environment.

I hope this helps anyone else struggling with this. The SuiteAnswers articles are unclear in this area and their support staff seem to be heavily dependent on those articles. It was only because I stumbled upon that menu item that I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Did you have to use your sandbox account in the url? I tried doing what you mentioned, but it still isn't finding any of my accounts. My sandbox account is under the system.netsuite.com url, now, and it won't let me change my sandbox environment to that url because it says it already exists (for production). Did you have to alter your environment urls?